# Can't run Spring Hello World keep getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring

EDIT: When I removed **PROVIDED** from the SPRING DEPENDENCY @ POM.XML it suddenly worked, can someone please tell me why it worked instead?

Hi guys I keep getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry
```

Whenever I try to execute

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.carlos.spring.FirstSpringHelloWorld"
```

my code

The code is as follows

```
package org.carlos.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import org.carlos.decoupled.MessageSource;
import org.carlos.decoupled.MessageDestination;

public class FirstSpringHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        DefaultListableBeanFactory bf = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();       
        BeanDefinitionReader reader = new PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader(bf);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/spring/helloworld-context.properties"));

        MessageSource source = (MessageSource) bf.getBean("source");
        MessageDestination destination = (MessageDestination) bf.getBean("destination");

        destination.write(source.getMessage());     
    }
}

package org.carlos.decoupled;

public interface MessageSource {
    String getMessage();
}


package org.carlos.decoupled;

public interface MessageDestination {
    void write(String message);    
}
```

and this is my POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.carlos.hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>hello Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>     
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hello</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

hello-world-context.properties:

```
source.(class)=org.carlos.decoupled.SimpleMessageSource
destination.(class)=org.carlos.decoupled.StdoutMessageDestination
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this? I'm at wits end :(

Comment: Try building a jar out of it , it will make all the lib available at runtime also.

Comment: Using mvn instal assembly:assembly? I'm quite new to MVN please elaborate ty!

Answer (score 1):

maven controls you compile time classpath, but does not control your runtime classpath.  Check your runtime classpath (often an environment variable named CLASSPATH) to make sure that all the dependancies are in the runtime classpath (including the spring jars).

Comment: I've got another sample here from http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/customizing.html how come I can directly run that app using mvn exec even though it relies on velocity, jaxen, dom4j and log4j?

Comment: Are velocity, jaxen, dom4j, and log4j already in your execution classpath?